# Feed native Javascript objects to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found interesting snippets in the following link: 
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html

The article describes how React works internally with native Javascript objects to build the tree.
Currently I'm working on a drag&drop editor for which I want to build a React component tree. Ideally I would build a tree of nested Javascript objects and convert them to a component tree at runtime.

For example, if I have an object like this (snippet from the link previousy added):

```
{
  type: Button,
  props: {
    children: 'OK!',
    color: 'blue'
  }
}
```

This is what react calculates internally. 
How do I feed this object (/object tree) immediately to React?

I think the snippets added are pseudo-code. The following for example will not work:

```
ReactDOM.render({
  type: Button,
  props: {
    children: 'OK!',
    color: 'blue'
  }
}, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra property as a security measure to avoid injection of components in JSON (It is impossible to create the required symbol from JSON).

It is explained in a [foot note](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#fn1):

> All React elements require an additional $$typeof:
>   Symbol.for('react.element') field declared on the object for security
>   reasons. It is omitted in the examples above. This blog entry uses
>   inline objects for elements to give you an idea of what’s happening
>   underneath but the code won’t run as is unless you either add $$typeof
>   to the elements, or change the code to use React.createElement() or
>   JSX.

```js
const Button = ({ color, children }) => <button style={{ background: color }}>{children}</button>;

ReactDOM.render({
  $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element'),
  type: Button,
  props: {
    children: 'OK!',
    color: 'blue'
  }
}, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```